# Sort Jobs by tag match on Careers

Tags: feature-request, tags, jobs

When looking for jobs on [Careers](https://careers.stackoverflow.com) I can sort the job list by date, job name or company name.

But since jobs have tags it would be great if there were another sort option that takes the tags into account I answer the most.

For instance Jobs having the most tags in common with my top 10 tags on Stack Overflow should be first in the list.

[image: screenshot]