# When is a notification sent?

Tags: support, notifications

When doing reviews and other things, I came across some scenarios where I don't know if notifications are sent. It would be helpful to know. I have a number of questions:

Do I get a notification when ...

1. my question is marked as *duplicate*, *too broad*, etc.?
2. my answer is deleted?
3. my comment is deleted?
4. my post is flagged?
5. someone writes a comment on the post, which I edited, `@`-mentioning me? Is there a difference between questions and answers? Is it time-dependent? Is only the last editor considered?
6. someone writes a comment on the question, which I closed or helped closing (I'm mentioned in the close text), `@`-mentioning me? Is it time-dependent?
7. someone edits my post successfully?
8. someone edits my post unsuccessfully (rejected edit)?
9. someone, who gave an answer to my question, edits this answer?

Are there differences between the sites? If yes, are they rooted in the beta status? Do the meta sites behave differently?

Comment: Isn't that all answered in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notifications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the questions can be answered.

1. [No](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/266187) - questions are deleted/closed silently, although they may be put [on hold] first.
2. [No](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3398/266187) - answers are deleted silently.
3. [No](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3398/266187) - comments are deleted silently.
4. No.
5. [Yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234814/266187) - any person who made a successful edit (either full edit or approved suggested edit) can be notified via comments. It's just that only those who have commented on the post will show up in the auto-complete.
6. Depends. Testing this proved that only a user with a binding close vote will be notified on a comment reply. Currently those can be diamond moderators or ordinary users with tag gold badge closing as duplicate.
7. [Yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236381/266187) - you get a notification of an edit to your posts.
8. Yes - because only a suggested edit could be "unsuccessful" so you would have been notified of the review.
9. [No](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225438/266187) - you're only notified of the original posting of the answer.

Comment: @animuson But [Servy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236879/266187) says 6. is no. Who is correct?

Comment: I'm testing it now

Comment: @animuson testing on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236861/sort-jobs-by-tag-match-on-careers) kind of proves you wrong, rene did not get notification. http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2212994#2212994 so probably only editors are candidates.

Comment: @Shadow Heh I can't find the post that said it worked for anyone in the history.

Comment: @animuson think it was in chat by a dev (Oded? balpha?) but maybe they said without really checking first.

Comment: *Diamond moderators* that closed a post can be @replied, regular users cannot.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are not notified if your question is closed.
2. You are not notified if your answer is deleted.
3. You are not notified if your comment is deleted.
4. You are not notified if your post is flagged.
5. You are notified if someone @replies you on a post that you edited or commented on.
6. You are not notified if someone @replies you on a post that you voted to close.
7. You are notified if someone edits your post.
8. You are notified if someone fails to edit your post.
9. You are not notified of edits to answers to questions you posted.